# Get the name of User who posted in a group in Connect API

Tags: apex, community, chatter, connect-api

I am creating a custom chatter page in Visualforce (kinda reinventing the wheel) by using Connect API. I am able to get the list of feeds for the user using the following connect API call:

```
feedElementPage = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.News, 'me');
```

When I am trying to display on page I am using Parent property of feedelement to display the user. It works fine when the parent is a user but in case of chatter post in a group, the parent is the group in which the chatter post is made. How can I get the name of the user who created the post in the group to display on page?

I looked into the documentation and could not find the relevant field on feedeleemnt. Also, CreatedBy field is not accessible for feedelement.

```
<apex:column width="18%">
    <apex:facet name="header">Sender</apex:facet>
    <a href="/{!feedElement.parent.id}">{!feedElement.parent.name} </a> 
</apex:column>
```

The above code displays User's name in case the post is by a user and group name in case its a group post. I need the name of user who posted in group e.g. Posted by  in

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It's the `actor` property of the feed item ([docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_feed_item.htm)).

Comment: Hi @alounie, Thanks for reply but we are working with feedelement not feeditem.

Comment: FeedElement is an abstract class. FeedItem the only subclass of FeedElement that has an actor property. You'll want to do an instanceof check to see if a FeedElement is a FeedItem, and then cast it to a ConnectApi.FeedItem if it is. The other feed element types (currently Recommendation and Bundle) do not have an actor property because they're system-generated and they don't have a "poster".